# Kendo scrollview(angular) next/prev methods use

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, scrollview

I am using kendo scrollview (angular) in my angular project, but I am not able to call next prev method provided by kendo.

Is there anyone who used it, and provide information for the same.

ANy example appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps...

1. Install Kendo scrollview using `ng add @progress/kendo-angular-scrollview`.
2. Import `BrowserAnimationsModule, ScrollViewModule` in the module which you are using.
3. Install kendo UI theme using `npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-default`.
4. Add `"node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"` in angular.json styles 
   array

   {
     "styles": [
       "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
     ]
   }

Then kendo UI will work as expected

Comment: Thanks, Scorll view is working fine, I just want to call API on next and prev button call.

Comment: You can call API on prev/next buttons using itemChanged event, Ex: <kendo-scrollview (itemChanged)="onItemChange($event)">. this event will return object with index and the array information of that index

Answer (score 0):

Use **itemChanged** event as below

```
<kendo-scrollview (itemChanged)="onItemChange($event)">

onItemChange(event) {
 console.log('onitemchage', event)
}
```

Result : {index: 1, item: {title: '', url: ''}}